# Issue with useDispatch hook - React Native/Redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-hooks

Couldn't find react native related help to the issue in previous posts.

I'm getting this message :

> invalid hook call. hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

My component is a functional component and all hooks (useState, useDispatch ) are called inside. 
Anyone gets this?

```
      export default function  LoginScreen (props) {
      const [name, setName] = useState("");
      const [message, setMessage] = useState("");


      const nextScreen = () => {
        // const dispatch = useDispatch();
        // dispatch(SendMessage(name, message));
        props.navigation.navigate("Chat", { name: name });
        return null
      };

      return (
        <View>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder="name..."
            onChangeText={userInput => {
              console.log(userInput);
              setName({ userInput });
            }}
            value={name}
          />
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder="message..."
            onChangeText={userInput => {
              console.log(userInput);
              setMessage({ userInput });
            }}
            value={message}
          />
          <View style={{ alignItems: "flex-end", marginTop: 64 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.nextScreen} onPress={nextScreen}>
              <Ionicons name="md-arrow-round-forward" size={24} color="#FFF" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) states:

> **Only Call Hooks at the Top Level**
>
> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or **nested functions**.
>   Instead, always use Hooks at the top
>   level of your React function. By following this rule, you ensure that
>   Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders.
>   That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks
>   between multiple useState and useEffect calls. (If you’re curious,
>   we’ll explain this in depth below.)

Call the hook in the body of the `LoginScreen` component, and the `dispatch` inside the `nextScreen` function:

```
export default function LoginScreen(props) {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  const dispatch = useDispatch(); // call hook and get dispatch

  const nextScreen = () => {
    dispatch(SendMessage(name, message)); // use dispatch
    props.navigation.navigate("Chat", {
      name: name
    });
    return null
  };
```